# Invalid consent request during to get the oauth token from the Snowflake

Tags: oauth-2.0, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I created an integration in the Snowflake and got a client id and when I tried to get an oauth token it is giving me an error stated that "Invalid consent request." but my username and password is correct. Please suggest me what can I do?